# React not importing css file

Tags: css, reactjs

I have followed the same structure with my .js and .css files as in their template but it's not importing/using my css. I am only getting it to work when the css is in the same file. Where am I going wrong?

.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Testcss.css';

export default function TestFunction(){
    return (
        <div class="ParentDiv">
            <div class="SubDiv">
                <h3>Some random text</h3>                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Testcss.css:

```
.SubDiv {
    border: 'green';
    background-color: 'orange';
    padding: "5px";
    max-width: '300px';
    font-size: 'small';
    margin: '15px';
    line-height: '2px';
    color: 'black';
    vertical-align: 'top';
    
}
.ParentDiv {
    background-color: "#282c34";
    min-height: "100vh";
    vertical-align: 'top';
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think, you do not put `"` or `'` in css values.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, that's where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

The import looks fine, but you're using the wrong syntax on your divs in the component. In react, you want to use className instead of class ([docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html))

try refactoring to this

```
import React from 'react';
import './Testcss.css';

export default function TestFunction(){
    return (
        <div className="ParentDiv">
            <div className="SubDiv">
                 <h3>Some random text</h3>                
            </div>
     </div>
 ).  
}
```

Comment: A `.jsx` isn't a requirement for writing JSX, FYI. It's typically just a way to easily differentiate React components from vanilla JS in the directory view, i.e. like IDEs using a different file icon.

Comment: thanks @DrewReese, I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Change `class` to `className`. And in *css* file, remove `'` and `"`, it should be like `border: green;`